# IOS - Objective C - How to stop executing periodic function when exiting the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a function in one of my viewControllers that I execute once every 10 seconds.

I want this function to stop it's execution when I exit the view.

I tried this peace of code :

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSError *error2;
    if ([_managedObjectContext save:&error2] == NO) {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Save should not fail\n%@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
        abort();
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Context Saved");



    [self stopTimer];
    NSLog(@"View will disappear now");
}
```

It is basicly calling the method stopTimer that will give a value of null to the timer.

```
- (void) stopTimer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

My problem is that my function keeps on executing even if I get out of my view. and never stops. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

This is the function called by my nstimer:

```
- (void) MyFunctionCalledByNSTimer
{
     [timer invalidate];
     timer  =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                     target:self selector:@selector(Function1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

I declare my nstimer in .m of my viewController

```
NSTimer *timer;
```

If you need more peaces of code just ask and I will edit the question.

Comment: `1)` Your `viewWillDisappear:` will not compile as it is missing a `}` - please add the full, correct method. `2)` You are not calling `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];` - please add this to your method. `3)` Please add the function, called by the timer, that is constantly running to the question. `4)` Please add the code that declares the timer and the method it will run.

Comment: can you please add code for creation of nstimer or where you have created nstimer?

Comment: @RoboticCat we don't need to call super viewWillDisappear unless we want to override it. The method will get called even though we didn't call super!

Comment: @RoboticCat I don't think it is missing a } , because i only have one instruction in my "else" statement therefore i don't need to use { .. }.

I will add the function called by the timer 


I edited the question, check it out.

Comment: @RonakChaniyara I edited the question check it out.

Comment: where are you calling MyFunctionCalledByNSTimer ?

Answer (score 3):

May be issue happening because of creating more than one timer and invalidating only what you have reference to.

So, may be modifying `MyFunctionCalledByNSTimer` like below will solve your problem:

```
- (void) MyFunctionCalledByNSTimer
{
     if(!timer){

          timer  =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                     target:self selector:@selector(Function1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     }

}
```

Now, only one timer reference will be there and `[timer invalidate]` will invalidate timer.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry but I just realized that my function is still executing even after I implemented this solution. 

I am confused now, yesterday it appeared to be working and now it's not. I hope you can help me, if you want additional informations about my code I am available.

Comment: set `timer=nil;` after `[timer invalidate]` and can't see another issue here@samouray

Answer (score 0):

Use this code 
call stopTimer on main thread

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSError *error2;
    if ([_managedObjectContext save:&error2] == NO) {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Save should not fail\n%@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
        abort();
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Context Saved");


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //Your main thread code goes in here
     [self stopTimer];       
    });


    NSLog(@"View will disappear now");
}
```

remember that you must send invalidate message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.

Comment: I just tried your code, it didn't work for me , as the function is still executing even if I exited its view. do you think it is correct to call the stoptimer method in viewWillDisappear ? because i saw in some answers to a question similar to mine people calling the stoptimer in viewDidDisappear

Comment: us can also fire a notification from previous viewcontroller viewwillappper method

Comment: also check that your timer have memory or not

Comment: @suthar : viewWillDisappear always gets called on main thread :) why dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{} ????

Comment: sometimes its cause problem thats why

Comment: @suthar I didn't understand what you meant by  firing a notification from previous viewcontroller viewwillappper method